# Associate Review to Movie when creating new Review using creatively named association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I decided to use a creatively named association so that I can have two type of Users, one that creates movies and one that reviews movies. The problem is I'm having trouble associating a Review to a Movie. Here are my Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :created_movies, :foreign_key => 'creator_id', :class_name => 'Movie'

  has_many :critiqued_movies, :through => :reviews

  has_many :reviews, :foreign_key => 'movie_critic_id'

end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'

  has_many :critics, :through => :reviews, :source => 'Review'

  has_many :reviews, :foreign_key => 'critiqued_movie_id'

end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :critiqued_movie, :class_name => 'Movie'
  belongs_to :movie_critic, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

My thinking was that I could find the particular movie in the Review.create action and then use .build to create the association:

```
  def create
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @review = @movie.reviews.build(review_params)
  .
  .
  .
  end
```

But this results in the following error in the Reviews.create action:

Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me get through this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a easy way to create associations, In your particular case, if you want to add a review to your movie, you can just simply do something like this:

```
@movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
@review = Review.new(review_params)

@movie.review << @review
```

I also suggest you to try this code on rails console first and see the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Soltex. I just tried your suggestion but i'm getting the same problem: Couldn't find Movie with 'id'= . The problem seems to be not getting the particular movie in the first place.

Comment: Where params[:id] comes from? You can use "render :text => params[:id].inspect" just in the beginning of your create to make sure it has some value in it and then check if your database has that movie id.

Comment: So @movie returns nil, which makes sense because there is no id. So any idea of how I can get the id there?

Comment: Yes, you need to supply that id when calling the create action, I suposse that you have any "link_to" anywhere in your view, so you must do something like this: <%= link_to 'create', {:controller => 'review', :action => 'create', :id => @movie.id} %>

Comment: I don't have a link_to, but a form_for: <%= form_for @review do |f| %>. I think the problem may be coming from here then.

Comment: You can access @ movie.id from inside that form_for? If so, you can save it in an hidden_field, like this: <%= f.hidden_field :anyname, :value => @ movie.id %>, and then inside your controller parameters.require(...), include this, {:anyname => []}, after that you can use that id, by doing params["review"]["anyname"], so, @ movie = Movie.find(params[:id]) would be @movie = Movie.find(params["review"]["anyname"])